# Jquery Selector Returning Null on Userscript

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I have an userscript running on chrome. I think jquery has been loaded because I used

```
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js
```

I am sure on the page that a table element exists and I've checked this line -

```
$('table')
```

In the console, and it gives back an array of tables. However, when I put this line in my userscript and log that into console, it returns a [].

What's going on?

Comment: Maybe the code is running before the DOM is ready?  Is your code in a `$(document).ready(function(){` (or `$(function(){`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code was returning `[]` because it was being ran before the DOM was ready.  You need to wrap your code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){})` (`$(function(){})` is shorthand).

```
$(function(){
    console.log($('table'));
});
```